# Finding the initial state in the power method for Hamiltonian diagonalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, hamiltonian, algorithms

In section III of the lecture note [Chapter 1: Exact Diagonalization](https://www.itp.uni-hannover.de/~weimer/teaching/QSim2013/exact-diagonalization.pdf), Weimer has described the Power method for Hamiltonian diagonalization.

The process requires the choice of an random initial state which has little but finite overlap with the ground state. Then applying the Hamiltonian and normalizing repetitively

> converge to the eigenvector with the largest absolute eigenvalue.

I am having difficulties to understand how this method works.

My questions:

1. What is the standard way to pick the random initial state?
2. Why do we assume that we will always know the ground state of the system?
3. If the ground state is not known, is the power method still applicable?

Comment: From what you write it seems that you only need to know more or less what does the ground state look like, but not necessarily know its exact form. If you don't know even that about your system then you are really lost on the dark.

Comment: @Blazej, could you please explain what you meant by 'look like'?

Comment: For example consider an electron in a spherically symmetric potential. If potential is complicated you will probably not be able to solve the eigenproblem exactly so you won't know the ground state explicitly. But you can be pretty sure that it is given by $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)$. Looking on how potential behaves near $r=0$ and $r \to \infty$ you can deduce the asymptotics of $R(r)$.  And Sturm-Liouville theorem even tells you how many zeros does $R(r)$ have.

Comment: Having that much information you can imagine roughly what your ground state looks like. Now using variational methods you can estimate its energy. All these informations will serve you as a guide in choosing good initial states. Most systems are not as simple as the one which I described. But there still will be some methods to extract some features of the ground state (and perhaps other states). If you can't solve the system exactly that sort of reasoning should always be done first, before all the approximations and numerical methods to get some insight what you are looking for.

Comment: And if you have some crazy Hamiltonian which you never saw before and have no ideas what properties it might have you are in a very bad position. It is difficult to even do numerics in such a case, because even in numerical methods you need to adopt the method to the problem at hand. And you must know what you are looking for.